# Rules of linear perturbation theory

Tags: calculus, physics, perturbation-theory

I am following a physics paper that uses linear perturbation theory. They take steps that imply things such as

$$\delta\left( \frac{1}{y} \right) = -\frac{\delta y}{y^2}$$

where $\delta$ is a small linear perturbation and $y$ is some function. It looks to me a bit like the second term in a Taylor series expansion, but I'm struggling to connect the dots.

What are the "rules" of the $\delta$ operator? Is there a text that gives its properties?

Comment: More or less by definition, for a function $f(x)$, $\delta(f(x)) = \frac{df}{dx} \delta x$, so the properties of $\delta$ are essentially those of the derivative. For example, $\delta(fg) = f (\delta g) + (\delta f) g$.

Comment: @Travis Thanks, that makes sense. How about when it's applied to a vector operation? For example what's $\delta\left( \nabla \cdot \vec y \right)$, where $\vec y$ is now a vector function?

Comment: This is a bit more complicated, since the function here is a multivariable one. For a multivariable function $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, we have $\delta f = f_1 \delta x^1 + \cdots + f_n \delta x^n$, where $f_k := \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}$.